# What Version of Street Fighter 2 comes packaged in the SNES Mini?

Tags: street-fighter-series, snes-classic

So I just purchased a SNES mini, with the intent of going back and playing the old street fighter 2 game.
I tried googling tips on how to play my character, and I quickly realized there was a lot more street fighter 2's than the one I bought.
Which version of Street Fighter was released on the SNES mini? Full name of the game please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the game is *Street Fighter II Turbo: Hyper Fighting*.

Source: [Wikipedia page for Street Fighter II Turbo: Hyper Fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_II_Turbo:_Hyper_Fighting)